# Creating static object in Global.asax and calling it from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, singleton

I have created a class in Global.asax like that:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();          

   //SHOULD I PUT THE LIST DESCRIBLED BELOW IN HERE?
}

public sealed class security
{
    private static readonly Lazy<security> lazy = new Lazy<security>(() => new security());

    public static security Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private security()
    {
    }

   //OR SHOULD I PUT THE LIST DESCRIBLED BELOW IN HERE?

}
```

Question:

1. I am using that to create a static list to be shared with all users. This is what I need: `public static List<permissionTemp> userPermissionSet { get; set; }`, but I am not sure where to put that line so it is created as soon as the application starts.
2. Once it is created, I need to get hold of this list to add an object that is created when a user log-in, but I don´t know how to call that class from the controller since it is in Global.asax

I am in doubt if I need to use the singleton patter or not since I will need to get the instance of this class every time I need to add an item to the list.. I presume yes!

Comment: It doesn't matter in **what particular** source file you write a type. There are a number of recommendations out there and if I dive into some of them you just broke one already (but that' ok). As I said. The fact that you declared the class in `Global.asax` doesn't make your controller unable to access it. A missing `using` or Assembly reference is what would do that. So.. the globally accessible singleton `security.Instance` is good. Don't worry about the singleton. That's not what will make your app run slow (other things will). And what exactly is the "THE LIST DESCRIBED BELOW" ?

Comment: n.b. Describled is not a word

Comment: @SpaceBison https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Describled&aq=f&oq=Describled&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.230&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo Yes, it googles Described. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a Singleton class containing the permission set and use it thruout the application.

```
public class PermissionManager{
    private PermissionManager() { UserPermissionSet = new List<permissionTemp>(); }
    private PermissionManager _instance;
    public PermissionManager Instance{
        get{ 
            if (_instance==null) _instance=new PermissionManager();
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    public List<permissionTemp> UserPermissionSet { get; private set; }
}
```

NOTE: just a simple implementation... you need to implement a thread safe constructor

then in the code you use

```
PermissionManager.Instance.UserPermissionSet
```

Comment: Are you sure this is right? PermissionManager is complaining "A get or set accessor expected" in public List<permissionTemp> UserPermissionSet { get; private set; } -- Check that: http://pbrd.co/Y3XrIU

Comment: No I just wrote it in SO without compliling. There were a couple of syntax errors. Now it compliles